# Is this the correct solution involving vector subspaces and basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, solution-verification

I need to find the basis and hence dimension of a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

1) $$U=\{(x,y,z):x=2y\}$$

Solution: We have $x=2y \iff y=\frac{x}{2}$ therefore we can write all elements in $U$ as the triple $(x,\frac{x}{2},z)$ for all real $x,z$. It is clear that we can make any vector in $U$ will have this form. However $(x,\frac{x}{2},z)=x(1,\frac{1}{2},0)+z(0,0,1)$ and so we have the basis of $U$ is given by $B=\{(1,\frac{1}{2},0),(0,0,1)\}$. Also $\operatorname{Dim}(U)=|B|=2$.

End problem.

Comment: That looks good, nice work!

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm very new to this concept so practice is a must for me cheers.

Comment: Nice that you answered yourself! +1